# Digital potentiometer - different voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, digital-logic, potentiometer

What would be the "correct" way to replace an analogue potentiometer with a microcontroller controlled digitalpotentiometer, when the require voltage is higher than what the chip can support?

In more detail: If I want to replace an analogue potentiometer for a 10 Vdc signal line with a digital potentiometer that only supports up to about 5 Vdc, what is the best way to achieve this ?

Is it a simple 5Vdc digital potentiometer with an opamp before/after to adjust the voltage accordingly ? Or...?

Please be specific - circuit diagrams for achieving this will be appreiciated. Basically, replace a basic manual potentiometer with a digital one, for a different voltage level.

Comment: Are you trying to adjust a voltage, or a resistance?

Comment: I believe it is the voltage. A signal line to control a motor (signal - not in-line)

Comment: Please be specific for what functional purpose do you want to replace the potentiometer. If it is used by the original circuitry to charge-discharge some voltage (like in many 555 circuits) then simple voltage translation (or DAC) won't do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about your circuit: I would use a DAC (Digital to Analog Converter).  If you can find a DAC that runs off 10V great, otherwise just use a 5V DAC and put an opamp with a gain of 2 in front of it (or even a 3.3V DAC and a gain of 3).

Your microcontroller will send a serial command to the DAC to set its output voltage.

This is what a non-inverting opamp circuit with a gain of 2 could look like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFpZ31.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is the difference between a digital potentiometer and a DAC really ? Both would adjust the voltage according to input signal ? 
Not really that much into electronics - can you provide some references of how to achieve this ? In particular the opamp circuit ? :)

Comment: A digital potentiometer is a device that takes a digital signal and varies the resistance of its output.  A DAC takes a digital signal and outputs a specified voltage.

Comment: So if a motor is controlled by the voltage (signal line adjusted by a manual potentiometer) a DAC would really achieve the same thing?

Comment: Sure.  You should see how much current this voltage signal input draws to make sure you can supply it, but yes.

Comment: So if voltage-controller, all I need to replace a "manual potentiometer", besides the microcontroller, is 2 resistors and an opamp ? :)

Comment: ...and the DAC. Yes. (Your microcontroller may have a built in DAC)

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: Without knowing more about the OP circuit this advice can be wrong. If the pot is used to control duty cycle in a 555 timer (pwm) generator (as in many cheap e-Bay-sourced boards), DAC won't work.

Comment: Very true (and worth mentioning), but without part numbers or schematics, I have to take OP's word at face value.